# Order results by number

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

Here is my code

```
$getlast = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `offersdone` group by uid");
$content .= "<table><tr><th>Username</th><th>Total Offers</th></tr>";
while($last = mysql_fetch_array($getlast)){
    $getuser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE ID='".$last['uid']."'");
    if (($user = mysql_fetch_array($getuser)){
        $getlast1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `offersdone` WHERE uid='".$user['ID']."'  ");
        $num1 = mysql_num_rows($getlast1);
        $content .= "<tr><td>" . $user['username'] . " </td><td> " . $num1 . "</td></tr>";
    }
}
```

The result comes like this:

```
Username    Total Offers
martin   15
dragan   1
mile1986 1
naramix  7
rrrob    55
sha09hh  17
shakest  1
```

Comment: I don't see a question mark anywhere. Try to explain what is that exactly you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT 
            u.username, 
            count(*) as count 
        FROM 
            offersdone o 
        LEFT JOIN 
            users u 
            ON u.ID = o.uid 
        GROUP BY
            o.uid 
        ORDER BY 
            count(*) DESC";
$getlast = mysql_query($sql);
$content .= "<table><tr><th>Username</th><th>Total Offers</th></tr>";
while($last = mysql_fetch_array($getlast)){
        $content .= "<tr><td>" . $last['username'] . " </td><td> " . $last['count'] . "</td></tr>";
}
```

This should select both username and the number of offers with one query and already sorted by the number of offers.

Demo:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM offersdone;
+-----+
| uid |
+-----+
|   1 |
|   1 |
|   2 |
|   2 |
|   2 |
|   2 |
+-----+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM users;
+----+----------+
| ID | username |
+----+----------+
|  1 | A        |
|  2 | B        |
+----+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT u.username, COUNT( * ) as count 
    -> FROM offersdone o
    -> LEFT JOIN users u ON u.ID = o.uid
    -> GROUP BY o.uid
    -> ORDER BY COUNT( * ) DESC;
+----------+-------+
| username | count |
+----------+-------+
| B        |     4 |
| A        |     2 |
+----------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your query " ORDER BY Total Offers ASC";